# Executing XSS payload when "http" is added to payload

Tags: web-application, xss

I have a context where every special characters are escaped properly except `':'` &`'/'`. The output is reflected inside `<a href="payload"` tag.

1 )When I set payload to `javascript:alert()`(which is the only payload I can think of in this context), it is reflected as `<a href="http://javascript:alert(1)"`

2) If the input payload is

```
javascript://%0aalert(1);//
```

The reflected output is `<a href="http://javascript://%0aalert(1);//"`
and when clicked opens as `http://javascript//%0aalert(1);//` .

Is any bypass possible in this context?

Comment: put the code you want to run on a server and enter that address as the payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, if you can't change the part before the colon, you are guaranteed to always produce a HTTP URL, no matter what you append.

This follows the *Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax* [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

> Each URI begins with a scheme name [...].

The syntax of the scheme part is specified as follows:

```
URI  = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
...
```

So, **no XSS is possible here** and you are limited to comparatively harmless vulnerability classes, which deal with HTTP URLs, such as [*open redirects*](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet) or *referer leakages* - depending on your scenario.